Evaluation of integration $\int \bigg(e^{2x}+2e^{x}-e^{-x}-1\bigg)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx$
Evaluation of
$\displaystyle =\int \bigg(e^{2x}+2e^{x}-e^{-x}-1\bigg)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx$
Try:
$\displaystyle =\int \bigg(e^{2x}+e^{x}-1+e^x-e^{-x}\bigg)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx$
$\displaystyle =\int (e^{2x}+e^x-1)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx+\int e^{e^x+e^{-x}}(e^x-e^{-x})dx$
$\displaystyle =\int e^x \cdot e^{e^x+e^{-x}}(e^x-e^{-x})dx+\int e^{x}\cdot e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx+\int e^{e^x+e^{-x}}(e^x-e^{-x})dx$
Apply by parts for (1) st
$\displaystyle = e^{x}\cdot e^{e^x+e^{-x}}-\int e^x\cdot  e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx+\int e^x\cdot e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx+e^{e^x+e^{-x}}+C$
$\displaystyle =(e^x+1)\cdot e^{e^x+e^{-x}}+C$
Please Help me to solve it using some short way, Thanks

Hint: after substituting $t=e^x$ the Ansatz $f(t)e^{t+t^{-1}}$ reduces to $t^2f'+(t^2-1)f=t^3+2t^2-t-1$, so if $f$ is polynomial its degree is $1$. That leaves only two degrees of freedom.

$$I=\int \bigg(e^{2x}+2e^{x}-e^{-x}-1\bigg)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx$$
$$I=\int \bigg(e^{2x}+e^{x}+e^{x}-e^{-x}-1\bigg)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}dx$$
$$I=\int (e^{2x}+e^{x}-1)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}\,dx+\int (e^{x}-e^{-x})(e^{e^x+e^{-x}})dx$$
Put $e^{e^x+e^{-x}}=t\implies e^{e^x+e^{-x}}(e^x-e^{-x})\,dx=dt$
$$I=\int (e^{2x}+e^{x}-1)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}\,dx+\int \,dt$$
Now dealing with the first integral,
$$\int (e^{2x}+e^{x}-1)e^{e^x+e^{-x}}\,dx$$
Multiply and Divide by $e^x$,
$$\int (e^{x}+1-e^{-x})e^{e^x+e^{-x}+x}\,dx$$
Put
$e^{e^x+e^{-x}+x}=u\implies (e^{x}+1-e^{-x})e^{e^x+e^{-x}+x}\,dx=du $ and proceeding, we get,
$$I=\int \,du+\int \,dt$$
$$I=e^{e^x+e^{-x}+x}+e^{e^x+e^{-x}}+C\implies (e^x+1)(e^{e^{x}+e^{-x}})+C$$
Or there exist a similar path using this
